# Use quicklz to compress a txt file

Tags: c, zip, compression

I am working with an arm-cortex, programming in C/C++. I am generating a CSV file with the board, which only contains numbers (amplitudes of microphone 16bit).
I want to compress this file using a portable, small and fast library so iI chose QuickLZ. (I don't need the best compression).
Here is the link: http://www.quicklz.com/download.html

I understand that the algorithm is supposed to check the characters in the file and compress so the src/dst are `char*`. I have tried to do some code but I obtained a 0 byte zip file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "quicklz.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *ifile = fopen("new_text_file.csv", "w");
    FILE *ofile = fopen("new_zip_file.zip", "w");
    char *src, *dst;

    if (ifile != NULL) {
        printf("OPEN SUCESS!\r\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("OPEN ERROR");
    }
    fprintf (ifile,"23483209489"); //Just for example

    ifile = fopen("new.csv", "r");
    qlz_state_compress *state_compress = (qlz_state_compress *)malloc(sizeof(qlz_state_compress));
    size_t len, len2;

    // allocate source buffer and read file
    fseek(ifile, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(ifile);
    fseek(ifile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    src = (char*) malloc(len);
    fread(src, 1, len, ifile);

    // allocate "uncompressed size" + 400 for the destination buffer
    dst = (char*) malloc(len + 400);

    // compress and write result
    len2 = qlz_compress(src, dst, len, state_compress);
    fwrite(dst, len2, 1, ofile);
    fclose(ifile);
    fclose(ofile);
 }
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". And in C don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. If your compiler complains, you don't use C.

Comment: You forget to close `ifile` before reopen it in read only mode. So, I suspect that ifile contains nothing, because of buffer (no closing, no `\n` so no flush to file) : just add `fclose(ifile);` before reopening

Comment: specific problem or error: file output is 0 bytes.
shortest code necessary: i can't write shorter
without a clear problem statement are not useful: it very useful, people will also know how to use the library for their projects.
There is no language "C/C++: since the 2 languages are supported, i wrote c/c++, but nevermind let say c++.

Comment: thanks Garf365 but now the zip file is unreadable.

Comment: hum, reading documentation about quicklz, for me, it doesn't create zip file. It uses another algo for compressing data - You have to use "qpress" to open it (http://www.quicklz.com/index.php)

Comment: yes you're write..but i see in qpress that it's  #include <windows.h> so it's not possible for me to implement in arm.maybe i need another lib..

Comment: In fact i don't need a especially a .zip archive. can i use quicklz to compress the txt file without converting it to zip format ?